# Is there some (free) MSWord-like editor such that it can directly render math symbols obtained from latex syntax?

Tags: editors, msword, word-to-latex

I wonder if there is a (free) MSWord like editor that can understand (virtually) any given math symbol? If we use some markdown editor, which can understand latex syntax, to obtain the output of `\mathbb{P}`, for example, and if we export this output as a .docx file, then it seems that the desired result would not correctly show up. I tried out the Typora with several open office pieces of software; but the result seemed unsatisfactory. However, for Typora, exporting as a .pdf file seems to work nicely.

My major tool is LaTeX editors themselves. I am looking for that option as my native language cannot be properly dealt with for most TeX editors so far. Although nearly all of my works are in English, it feels like a pity to be unable to write math along with my native language. Typora happens to furnish the possibility for my native language to work with mathematics. Since it would be cumbersome for Typora to do page breaks, I was thinking to use Typora as a draft (for the scientific documents in my native language) and then export the result as a .docx file to fulfill the goal.

Thanks.

Comment: Try LyX: https://www.lyx.org/

Comment: try Scientific word also. I've been using it for years.  I use version 5.5 and not V 6.0 they released 3 years ago. I prefer V 5.5. It is commercial product.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess I should delineate the scope of my question earlier.

Comment: You mention "my native language cannot be properly dealt with for most TeX editors so far" - if you could share, what is your native language? There are a lot of packages and options out there, and perhaps your situation can be solved by adjusting what you use with LaTeX, rather than using other programs / environments.

Comment: I believe the correct term is a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor.  MSWord like could mean almost anything.